# how to select nth element of array in a tuple?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tuple like this:

> (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]))

I would like to select the first element of each array in this tuple and want to achieve this result:
[0,0] or [0,1] or [0,2]

How can I do this?

Actually, this tuple is obtained from a function in numpy.where
what I do is like this:

> import numpy as np
>
> x=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>
> xi=np.where(x<4)

any suggestion?

Comment: uhhhh,  I just get the answer after I asked it XD

zip(*xi)[0] or zip(*xi)[1] or zip(*xi)[2]

Comment: getXi = lambda X, i: (X[0][i], X[1][i]);  print(getXi(xi, 1))

Comment: You may want to look at [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

Comment: @BradSolomon I am not sure if it is the same situation: I am considering array in tuple, but the issue you posted is tuple in list. but I found the answer is alike. thank you

Comment: @Silencer: thanks~

Comment: @user2357112: this is awesome. I don't know this function~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
list(zip(tp[0],tp[1]))
Out[689]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]
```

Data input

```
tp=(np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 2]))
```

If you want to list of list

```
l=list(zip(tp[0],tp[1]))
list(map(list, l))
Out[691]: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the numpy array through `nditer` and pair them:

```
np.array([(x,y) for x,y in np.nditer(xi)]) 

array([[0, 0],
   [0, 1],
   [0, 2]], dtype=int32)
```